# Detect x-value of right-most black pixel within a monochrome image?

Tags: bash, shell, imagemagick

I'm attempting to script up something to convert some historical typefaces off of a Mac Plus emulator. I've got it where it screen captures each glyph individually, and I've pre-calculated the the height and left margin of it which allows me to *mostly* crop it the way I need. But these fonts seem to be proportional, and several characters are wider than the rest.

Is it possible with shell script tools to determine the x value of the right-most black pixels? Since I'm already using Imagemagick, can it do this itself? I had intended for this to be a quick and dirty project, so I'd like to avoid heavier scripting languages (perl, python) if at all possible.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show a couple of sample images. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Not sure why it should matter, but edited to include the images. MacWrite 1.0 bitmap Geneva, at 12pt Bold.

Comment: It's easier to suggest solutions to problems you can see Try `convert YOURIMAGE format %@ info:` to get the trim box.

Comment: So for your first image, you get `6x10+1+5` meaning that the `g` is 6px wide by 10px tall starting at `x=1`, `y=5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to get the trim box:

```
magick YOURIMAGE format %@ info:
6x10+1+5
```

You can read the width, height, x-offset and y-offset into `bash` variables like this:

```
IFS='[x+]' read w h x y < <(magick YOURIMAGE -format %@ info:)
```

You can add `w` and `x` with:

```
((right=w+x))
```

You may, or may not, want to subtract 1 from the answer above.

---

I don't know what you are actually trying to do, but you maybe just want to trim your letters to their smallest bounding box:

```
magick YOURIMAGE -trim result.png
```

Comment: It looks like I could just use -trim itself to trim off the right side... I never knew it could do that. And I just discovered the fx expressions... I can literally calculate within a single mogrify the exact width I need. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You could spend half a life-time learning its abilities Fortunately Anthony Thyssen has done most of it for us here... https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/